# Input table and column name in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to complete a task that says:
*Search in the user given table, in the user given column the user given value using explicite cursor.* This means I have to use the `&` operator to input the table name, column name and value. If I found the given object, give a `varchar` *found* else *not found.* How to input the table name, column name and the value (that is of correct type of course)? 
I tried it but failed miserably:

```
declare
@Mytable varchar2;
@Mycolumn varchar2;
Myvalue @Mycolumn%TYPE;
oneLine @Mytable%ROWTYPE;
found varchar2;
cursor kurzor is select * from @Mytable;
begin
open kurzor;
loop
fetch kurzor into oneLine;
if oneLine.@Mycolumn = Myvalue then
found='found';
end if;
exit when kurzor%NOTFOUND;
end loop;
close kurzor;
end;
/
```

Comment: Sadly, a cursor is the wrong way to implement this logic.  It is a shame that you are learning to do something inefficiently.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the way

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
@GordonLinoff indeed it is, though I'm expected to, a specifically given homework this is. :( I'l ask the teacher of Dynamic sql or to ease this task to suit our "toolkit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to describe variables for table name, column name and etc. in section `DECLARE`. Just use substitution variables.

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR cur IS  SELECT &myColumn FROM  &myTable;
    currentVal VARCHAR2(4000);
    isFound    VARCHAR2(10):= 'not found';  
BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO currentVal;
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;

        IF currentVal = &myValue THEN
            isFound:= 'found';
            EXIT; 
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;
    dbms_output.put_line(isFound);
END;
```